# Wi-Fi Adapter Not Found on Lenovo Yoga C940 under Bionic Beaver 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS from a bootable USB drive on a Lenovo Yoga C940 15.6" laptop that does not have an Ethernet network adapter - only wireless. The wireless adapter did work under Windows 10 (before I erased it with this install). Problem: Ubuntu does not see the Wi-Fi adapter and I can not connect to the internet.

```
    lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
6e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I do have access to another Linux box with the internet connection. Could someone please help as this Lenovo Yoga C940 is next to useless without the functioning Wi-Fi adapter since it is the only way to connect to the internet? Thanks in advance. Tried re-installing things a couple of times and rebooting the box couple of times just in case - nothing worked.

If it matters, I have an older Lenovo Yoga 730 model and the Bionic Beaver installation on it about a year ago worked flawlessly.

As was asked in the comments:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

comes back empty - no output.

Comment: What is the kernel version? Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: uname -r returned 5.0.0-23-generic. Ok, just did: dmesg | grep iwl comes back empty.

Comment: Connect to the internet using other means, e.g. a phone connected to USB and update the system.

Comment: Another way is to install 18.04.4.

Comment: Ok, trying to connect to the internet via a phone ...

Comment: Connected. Running sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

Comment: Thank you Pilot6 - after running the "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y" command for about 30 minutes, I did "sudo reboot" and after the box came up Ubuntu noticed the Wi-Fi adapter and the problem is solved! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade packages in your system or install Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Connect to the internet using your phone and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-firmware
```

That will save time and traffic, instead of `sudo apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the helpful input from the user Pilot6 - not really sure how I can thank her/him.
The key was to connect the Lenovo Yoga C940 laptop to an Android cell phone via a USB cable, which established what Ubuntu saw as a *wired* connection to the internet.
Once connected to the internet, I ran

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

for about 30 minutes. Once the above command finished:

```
sudo reboot
```

and the box came up with the Wi-Fi adapter visible and functioning. Configuring the actual Wi-Fi connection was a breeze. Thank you Pilot6.

(in case you guys need help with math, (theoretical) physics, comp sci or computer programming questions to return the favor - I am your guy on Quora)

Just in case:

```
    dmesg | grep iwl
[   11.198224] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[   11.198227] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   11.198229] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[   11.198447] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   11.244792] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[   11.259307] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   11.259798] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   11.445291] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: base HW address: 8c:c6:81:f0:35:5c
[   11.502273] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0 wlp115s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.558565] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   11.743537] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   11.750758] iwlwifi 0000:73:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

is what I get now on the box.

Comment: You could upgrade only kernel and firmware, but I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Thank you - I will keep this in mind for future installs. I upvoted your answer but my upvote was not rendered visible for the public.

Comment: You better install 18.04.4. It already has all you need.